# MSTest in VS2010 - How to launch all loadtests in a single step

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest, load-testing

In the new team I work for we use a lot of unit tests, we use MSTest in VS2010.

I have prepared about 10 loadtest to use these unit tests in various ways.  How do you launch all the loadtest (randomly or with a specified order)?

I'm having trouble how to get the standard VS environment to do this.

Or maybe there is a plugin to add to Visual Studio?

Comment: Do you want the load tests to run simultaneously or one after the other?

Comment: one after another, in sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the `Test View` window, by selecting `Tests --> Windows --> Test View`
2. In the `Test View`, select `Group By: Test Type`.
3. Right click on the `Load Test` category and `Run Selection`.

[image]

Comment: I thought to categories to keep unit tests together but I didn't think to group them and in this way! At least if I'm on the PC I can do it as I need... great, thanks!